# How to troubleshoot Firefox Addon: could not be installed because it is not compatible with Firefox <x.x.x.x>

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I created a simple extension based on an existing one, but when I try to test it and add to Firefox manually I get this general error message:

```
<Extension Name> could not be installed because it is not compatible with Firefox <x.x.x.x>
```

How can I troubleshoot this?

I even tried setting maxVersion to a high value in install.rdf.

```
                <em:maxVersion>150</em:maxVersion>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Eventually I dropped the whole manual addon building stuff and went with http://builder.addons.mozilla.org
I find the Firefox developer experience very poor compared to that of Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have verified that you have the correct minVersion and maxVersion, the other thing that can cause this is an invalid updateURL.

The Firefox bug about this is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740378

If you are planning to host your add-on on addons.mozilla.org, you do not need an updateURL and if you are in the process of developing an add-on, there should be no updateURL in your install.rdf at all.

Comment: Sorry about that. I answered from my phone which was silly. I should have just waited.

Answer (score 2):

If `minVersion` and `maxVersion` are correct but your extension still doesn't install then these values are probably overridden. In addition to the values in `install.rdf` Firefox will also look up the update URL of your extension and get updated compatibility information from there. This information takes priority over whatever you specify in `install.rdf`.

If you specify an `updateURL` explicitly then you should update the information in the file it points to and clear the browser cache. If you don't specify an `updateURL` then by default it points to [addons.mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/). If an extension with the same ID and version number is found on addons.mozilla.org then its compatibility information is taken over. If that's the case then changing the version number in `install.rdf` to something unknown to addons.mozilla.org should be sufficient (obviously, you should also change extension ID of the extension hosted on addons.mozilla.org isn't yours).

Plus there is the bug mentioned by Mike Kaply of course - bad error message if an insecure `updateURL` is specified and no `updateKey`.

Answer (score 1):

Your max version should look something like:

```
<em:maxVersion>17.*</em:maxVersion>
```

That indicates the max version of Firefox that supports the extension. Firefox 150 is a long way off! ;-)

Do you have the source code posted anywhere? I'd be glad to take a look. I've written a couple of Firefox extensions now, so I'm sure I can help.

Comment: Still, having 150 as `maxVersion` should work with current versions - definitely not related to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, check https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/unable-install-add-ons-extensions-or-themes to see if any of those reasons apply.

With the release of Firefox 57 (14 Nov 2017), developers can no longer build "legacy" add-on .xpi files locally and load them in Firefox, [only add-ons built using the webextensions API will load](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2017/02/16/the-road-to-firefox-57-compatibility-milestones/).

Hope this helps :)